# Assigning unique id to each instance in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe df in R as below:

```
>df
#x
#a
#b
#a
#c
#b
```

I want a new dataframe that assigns unique id for each instance as follows:

```
>df

#x y
#a 1
#b 1
#a 2
#c 1
#b 2
```

Any help would by highly appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(x=c("a", "b", "a", "c", "b"))

df %>% group_by(x) %>% mutate(y=1:length(x))
# Source: local data frame [5 x 2]
# Groups: x [3]

#       x     y
#   (fctr) (int)
# 1      a     1
# 2      b     1
# 3      a     2
# 4      c     1
# 5      b     2
```

Using `row_number` in `dplyr`.

```
df %>% group_by(x) %>% mutate(y=row_number(x))
```

Comment: There is `row_number()` function in `dplyr`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `ave` and specify the `FUN` as `seq_along`, grouped by the 'x' column.

```
df$y <- with(df, ave(x, x, FUN=seq_along))
df
#  x y
#1 a 1
#2 b 1
#3 a 2
#4 c 1
#5 b 2
```

---

Or use `getanID` from `splitstackshape`

```
library(splitstackshape)
getanID(df, 'x')[]
```

---

Or use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, y:= seq_len(.N), by =x]
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(x = c("a", "b", "a", "c", "b")), 
.Names = "x", row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```